# Bootstrap: Column White Space Text Fill

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am using uib-accordions to display some data. I have defined accordion header as a row and split it into various columns to display various data elements. 

[Accordion View in Small and larger screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdrCc.png) |
[Accodion View in XS scren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwZAM.png)
Column distribution:
Store ID (col-xs-12 col-sm-5)
Controls (col-xs-12 col-sm-5): [SFS (Col-xs-4), BOPIS(col-xs-4), BOSTS(col-xs-4)]
Arrow Icon (col-xs-2 col-sm-1)

Now in small view all the glyphicon icon elements split into next row. I am trying to get display these icons in the same row as their labels, and there seems to be empty space available.

Secondly, how do we align phone, address and various toggle switch properly into a grid ? I have tried various options to center the toggle switches and save button, but it always breaks the view.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <hr>
        <h4> Search: </h4>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="mycontainer row row-content" ng-controller="MainController" style="padding-top:100px" ng-cloak>
        <uib-accordion close-others="true" ng-controller="ItemController" >
            <div uib-accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <uib-accordion-heading>
                    <div class="row" style="padding-top:3px">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 ">
                            Store ID #: {{item.storeid}} | {{item.desc}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                **<div class="col-xs-4">SFS <span ng-if="item.SFS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><span ng-if="!item.SFS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">BOPIS <span ng-if="item.BOPIS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><span ng-if="!item.BOPIS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">BOSTS <span ng-if="item.BOSTS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><span ng-if="!item.BOSTS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></div>
                            </div>**
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 ">
                            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <a ng-href="tel:{{item.phone}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone "></span> Phone: {{item.phone}}<br>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Address: {{item.address}}<br>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            SFS: 
                            <toggle ng-model="item.SFS" aria-label="SFS Switch"></toggle>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            BOPIS: 
                            <toggle ng-model="item.BOPIS" aria-label="SFS Switch"></toggle>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            BOSTS: 
                            <toggle ng-model="item.BOSTS" aria-label="SFS Switch"></toggle>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-primary .btn-sm">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </uib-accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/rFa5pgA0rv)**: https://www.bootply.com/rFa5pgA0rv

**CSS:**

```
.nowrap{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .pull-right-xs{float:right;}
}
```

**Kind of HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <hr>
        <h4> Search: </h4>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="mycontainer row row-content" ng-controller="MainController" style="padding-top:100px" ng-cloak>
        <uib-accordion close-others="true" ng-controller="ItemController" >
            <div uib-accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <uib-accordion-heading>
                    <div class="row" style="padding-top:3px">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 ">
                            Store ID #: {{item.storeid}} | {{item.desc}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="row">
                                **<div class="col-xs-4 nowrap">SFS <span ng-if="item.SFS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><span ng-if="!item.SFS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 nowrap">BOPIS <span ng-if="item.BOPIS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><span ng-if="!item.BOPIS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 nowrap">BOSTS <span ng-if="item.BOSTS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span><span ng-if="!item.BOSTS" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></div>
                            </div>**
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 ">
                            <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isopen}"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                        <a ng-href="tel:{{item.phone}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone "></span> Phone: {{item.phone}}<br>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Address: {{item.address}}<br>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            SFS: 
                            <toggle class="pull-right-xs" ng-model="item.SFS" aria-label="SFS Switch">toggle</toggle>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            BOPIS: 
                            <toggle class="pull-right-xs" ng-model="item.BOPIS" aria-label="SFS Switch">toggle</toggle>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            BOSTS: 
                            <toggle class="pull-right-xs" ng-model="item.BOSTS" aria-label="SFS Switch">toggle</toggle>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12"> 
                        <button class="btn btn-primary .btn-sm">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </uib-accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nowrap does the trick to fill up white space (+1). I should have been more clear earlier: for toggle buttons I am trying to center them in the extra small view, whereas they remain in line for smaller screen (as per attached image). Similarly, I am trying to center the save button as well (for all screen size). 

I have tried using offset, but that breaks the view.

Comment: Also, how do I align phone #, and address field properly, equally spaced from ':'. (zipcode breaks into next line under address label, instead of breaking under the address value)

In smaller and larger screens, can I align the toggle buttons under respective accordion header properly(there is slight shift, besides equal column distribution)?

Comment: Here is new one https://www.bootply.com/rFa5pgA0rv , but can you share the final html in a fiddle, I don't code with angular, I don't know how its render

Comment: Thank you, it did help to an extent. I used the nowrap class to fill in white-space for phone, but the address still breaks. If i use nowrap on address, the bootstrap grid system breaks, creating a horizontal scroll. Also can i create some wrapper to bind and properly align the SFS/BOSTS/BOPIS fields with their toggle buttons.
Fiddle link: https://www.bootply.com/SdSAF1J0gc (dependencies configured locally and not CDN)